# Does a Hexblade warlock get Hex Warrior's Cha bonus with a versatile weapon without Pact of the Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, hexblade

I'm a first level Warlock, [Hexblade archetype](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheHexblade) from *Xanathar's Guide To Everything*. My question is:

Would a weapon with the Versatile property work with the Hex Warrior ability **without Pact of the Blade** if I fight in two-handed mode?

The Hex Warrior feature says (XGtE 55-56) :

> The influence of your patron also allows you to mystically channel
>   your will through a particular weapon. Whenever you finish a long
>   rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that
>   **lacks the two-handed property**. When you attack with that weapon, you
>   can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for
>   the attack and damage rolls. This benefit lasts until you finish a
>   long rest. If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this
>   benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no
>   matter the weapon's type.

The Versatile [weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) says (PHB 147):

> This weapon **can be used** with one or **two hands**. A damage
>   value in parentheses appears with the property—the damage when the
>   weapon is **used with two hands** to make a melee attack.

And the Two-Handed property says (PHB 146):

> This weapon requires two hands when you attack with it.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between an option and a requirement?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, the effect still applies

Using a weapon with two hands does not automatically give a weapon the "two-handed" property which is a specific property of certain weapons ([SRD p.65](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)):

> Two-­Handed: This weapon requires two hands when you attack with it

Using a Versatile weapon with two hands simply changes the damage dealt by the weapon, it does not grant or remove properties from the weapon.

See also [this tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/831283161149509632?lang=en) which supports this claim.

> **Pedro Coelho** @rockhollyrabbit · [13 Feb 2017](https://twitter.com/rockhollyrabbit/status/831281406751948800)
>   @JeremyECrawford for the Hexblade pact's Hex Warrior does the 2handed thing include versatile weapons wielded 2 handed or just pure 2handed?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford · [13 Feb 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/831283161149509632)
>   Two-handed and versatile are two different weapon properties (PH, 146–7). A reference to one is not a reference to the other: A ≠ B.
>
> **Gerardo Ramirez Arme** @mex_rage [13 Feb 2017](https://twitter.com/mex_rage/status/831283599831752704)
>   so hexblade works with a longsword hold in 2 hands then
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford [13 Feb 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/831283782523117571)
>   That's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfornately, Im not sure if you are right. Do you have any other supporting evidence?

Comment: @Elmo I have added a tweet from Jeremy Crawford to support this

Comment: @Elmo the feature specifically calls out "the two-handed property", not "used in two hands" or similar

Comment: While I don't believe that the Crawford tweet is necessary, given your explanation of the versatile property, and the clarity of the rules, giving amplifying information where the answer is still unclear to the asker is a nice example of going the extra mile. :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast My DM might have another opinion. I just wanted to be sure.